# How to merge facebook account into existing account with Devise

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise, omniauth

I followed the steps [here](http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2011/05/06/how-to-merge-facebook-account-into-existing-user-account-using-devise/) and was running into some problems in merging the accounts

Based on the instructions, I added the following method to my ApplicationController

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  # Merge data from Facebook with her current account
  if session["facebook_data"] && current_user.facebook_uid.nil?
    current_user.facebook_uid = session["facebook_data"]["uid"]
    current_user.save(:validate => false)
  end

  # Countermeasure against session fixation
  session.keys.grep(/^facebook\./).each { |k| session.delete(k) }

  super
end
```

However, I'm getting a null session["facebook_data"] in the ApplicationController, even though I'm seeing the correct session value in the callback app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb that calls this method:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if user && user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_session_url # this redirect invokes the after_sign_in_path_for method in ApplicationController
    end
  end

end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of many reasons, the two reasons worth checking for this:

**1)** The `session["facebook_data"]` in `ApplicationController` is being called before it is being set in `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`.

**Solution:** Check if the calling of the two controllers is in proper synch **i.e.**

- It should be first `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` and then `ApplicationController`.

**2)** The value of `session["facebook_data"]` is reset to **null** after its set in `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`.

**Solution:** Trace the calls after the `session["facebook_data"]` value set in `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` upto the call to `session["facebook_data"]` in `ApplicationController`.

Comment: I realized that it's because the session["facebook_data"] got set to null but isn't able to identify which controller is doing this. I ended up adding another hash key session["foo"] = session["facebook_data"] and was successful in passing the value with session["foo"]